# Bug on google Chrome when showing PDF

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, pdf

Recently a have been faced with a problem on Google Chrome I don't know if this error is in the google or in my code;

If set the div as display: none; and show it again the PDF-view show only grey background; if I do a zoom in or out, it appears again;

To illustrate the error a took theses screenshots;

My Google Chrome version is 91.0.4472.77 64 bits

[image]

After display:none

[image]

Comment: Where is the div that you are setting as `display: none`?

Comment: In the main page; it like a tabs, when i change the tab and go back where is the pdf, become gray

Comment: It sounds like you're going into Chrome Inspect tool and setting the div to `display: none`. Maybe... *don't* do that?

Comment: Yes, I did and its became gray again. If i put the hidden attribuite or visible: hiden, or anything that hidden it, do became gray again, looks like the pdf-viewer initialize again, but if i do  zoom in or zoom out  it show the pdf again

Answer (score 1):

I reported the bug on Chrome Issues and they will Fix this issue in the next update of **Google Chrome**;

Follow the link: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1218930#c_ts1624205770

Comment: Thanks for submitting this and linking it here.  We randomly started encountering this behavior as well.  I downloaded the "dev" build and can confirm the original pdf viewer behavior is restored and do not get the blank pdf viewer.  To save anyone the click the fix is expected to be released for mainline Chrome in Sept. 2021